# Android Room Kotlin is it possible to draw a random object from the database?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Is it possible to draw a random object from a database built with Room and put it into the variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `random` function as SQL.

```kotlin
@Dao
interface SomeDao {
    @Query("select * from some_table order by random() limit 1")
    fun findRandom(): SomeEntity
}
```